# Uninstall/Rollback 11.04?

Tags: 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I return to 10.10 from 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36025/how-can-i-return-to-10-10-from-11-04)

I foolishly upgraded my Ubuntu installation to 11.04.  Even with "classic" mode it is dog slow. The GUI is herky-jerky and before it was fine.

I want to go back to what I had before.

Is there a way of rolling back/uninstalling the 11.04 upgrade or do I have to clean install 10.x?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new here: Could you do us favor before your do? See if you are running the **recommended** videocard driver.There have been issues with running the latest one. 
Ubuntu 11.04 **should** not be alot slower than 10.10. Booting is a bit slower, ok but not alot to make a difference. The desktop itself should not be slower.

If you do want to go back to 10.10: reinstall is indeed the best option. It is the best option to make sure nothing from 11.04 stays on your system what could possible disturn your 10.04 setup.

Besides the link Takkat posted also have a look at the other [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38698/how-do-i-downgrade-from-11-04-to-10-10) on the right hand side under 'related' with almost the same titles since [Duplicate questions](https://askubuntu.com/faq) do get closed on askubuntu.